# Can I pull ampere out of transformer as I want not as my circuit need?

Tags: transformer, battery-charging

I have transformer with max ampere 20Amp, If I tried to charge 12V battery with it, it gives 2Amp..I want to do something that force transformer to gives 10Amp for example...Is that even possible?

**UPDATE:**
The goal is to charge the battery with 10A rather than 2A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current supplied by the transformer will be mostly determined by the load you put on it - for a given AC input voltage.

To get your transformer to output more than the 2A that you are feeding into your 12V battery you would have to put a different sized load on it. In this specific case you would have to present a load to the transformer that was roughly one fifth the impedance of your 12V battery to get the current up to 10A.

I do not know just what your goal is in asking this question as you did not specify. But if you are thinking that 10A would be useful in charging your 12V battery faster then there is a bit for you to investigate and learn about battery charging techniques. Also you would have to determine if that is even safe for the battery you are charging.

But just as a general comment the main way to drive more current into a given load is to raise the applied voltage at the load. For a transformer supply that could mean raising the input AC voltage some OR acquiring a transformer that had a different primary to secondary turns ratio.

Comment: Yes the goal is to charge battery with 10A

Comment: Then as I said you have a good bit if investigation to do. Learn about how charging profiles for your specific battery technology work. Learn just what the specific battery you have is capable of accepting in terms of applied charging voltage. Etc. At the same time note that arbitrarily increasing the voltage to your battery so as to get it to accept 5X the amount of current is likely to lead to a very unsafe situation and may result in a serious battery over temperature condition and explosion.